# searching and matching observations in single dataset with sas

Tags: sas

I have data like this,

```
external-id M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5
P1          AA AG ZZ -/- GG
P2          AA AA AA GG  GG
```

I want to see both P1 and P2 contains same data or not, if same I will give equal otherwise not equal and storing them in dummyvariables VAR1 to VAR5. How do I do this in SAS?

I am expecting data like this

```
external-id M1 M2 M3 M4 M5   VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 VAR4 VAR5
P1          AA AG ZZ -/- GG  EQ   NE   EQ    EQ  EQ
P2          AA AA AA GG  GG
```

I want to consider if either P1 or P2 have ZZ,-/- are equal. Is array programming helpful for this?

Comment: Have you thought about transposing this table so that M1-M5 would be your rows, and P1 & P2 would be your variables?  This would allow you make a variable `match`, and say: `if P1 = P2 then match='EQ'; else match='NE';`

Answer (score 1):

This probably is not a good idea, because it sounds like your data structure needs to be reconsidered.  In particular, the ending data structure doesn't seem very useful; but perhaps you are giving too small a set of examples to understand your true purpose.

That said, here is how you could do the specific example.  If you have other considerations, this may or may not work.

I use LAG in an IFC( ) branch; if you use IF instead, you cannot use LAG in this fashion as it will not work as expected - you either need to LAG into a new set of temporary variables, or you need to use RETAIN.

```
data have;
input (externalid M1 M2 M3 M4 M5) ($);
datalines;
P1          AA AG ZZ -/- GG
P2          AA AA AA GG  GG
;;;;
run;


data want;
set have;
array ms m1-m5;
array vars $ var1-var5;
do _t = 1 to dim(ms);
  vars[_t] = ifc(ms[_t]=lag(ms[_t]) or ms[_t] in ('ZZ','-/-') or lag(ms[_t]) in ('ZZ','-/-'),'EQ','NE');
end;
if _N_ = 1 then call missing(of vars[*]);
drop _t;
run;
```

Comment: Joe Thank you very much for your help in solving my problem your suggestion working very good and thanks lot for your help